"Stretchable" JLabel with dynamic text
I don't like scrollbars for their clumsiness. I wrote a custom JLabel extension that dynamically trims the label's text on each paint() call and appends with an ellipsis
package StretchableLabel;

import lombok.SneakyThrows;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class StretchableLabel extends JLabel {
    private String originalText;
    public StretchableLabel(String text) {
        super(text);
        this.originalText = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.originalText = text;
        String displayedText = trimTextIfNecessary(text);
        super.setText(displayedText);
    }

    private String trimTextIfNecessary(String text) {
        if (getFont() == null) return text;
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
        int textWidth = fontMetrics.stringWidth(text);
        int parentWidth = getParent().getWidth();
        if (textWidth > parentWidth) {
            return trimText(text, parentWidth, fontMetrics);
        } else {
            return text;
        }
    }

    private String trimText(String text, int parentWidth, FontMetrics fontMetrics) {
        int textLimit = parentWidth / fontMetrics.charWidth('m');
        return text.substring(0, textLimit) + "...";
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        String displayedText = trimTextIfNecessary(originalText);
        super.setText(displayedText);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}

package StretchableLabel;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("StretchableLabel Demo");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        StretchableLabel label = new StretchableLabel((StringUtils.repeat("long label ", 20)));
        panel.add(label);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}



Drawbacks:

I believe getText() should return the same value that was set with setText() (an original string). However, getText() returns an actual, displayed text while setText() sets a trimmed text. I can't override getText() since it's invoked by paintComponent() -- unless I check the caller which is tricky. It's important to intercept any setText() calls, as I do, so that direct text setting is not possible by the class's clients
Checking the width of m is too conservative. It would be more precise to check the right substring length by applying some binary search algorithm on the string (though it would be worse from the performance standpoint)
I'm not sure comparing the length of the text with the parent's width is a good idea as the parent can contain other children

How do I properly implement my idea?

I wrote a custom JLabel extension that dynamically trims the label's text on each paint() call and appends with an ellipsis - Not understanding the problem. This is the default behaviour of the JLabel. When the "size" is less that the "preferred size", the text will be truncated and the "..." added. Many people will add the text as a tooltip, so the enitre text can be displayed.

You are implementing a feature that does already exist. Apparently, there is a bug in the Basic/Metal Look&Feel that makes it calculating with wrong sizes when no font has been set.
There are two simple solutions to this

Set a font explicitly
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("StretchableLabel Demo");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("long label ".repeat(20));
    label.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, 0, 16));
    frame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(frame.getWidth() >> 1, frame.getHeight());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


Use the system (i.e. Windows) Look&Feel
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch(ReflectiveOperationException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("StretchableLabel Demo");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("long label ".repeat(20));
    frame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(frame.getWidth() >> 1, frame.getHeight());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}



In both cases you get the intended feature, clipping the text and appending an ellipsis, for free. Keep in mind that you have to set up the layout manager such that they will shrink the JLabel when there’s not enough space.

No, it doesn't work. I tried both adding label.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 16)) after the call to setOpaque(true) and setting the L&F first line

There is no setOpaque(true), neither in your code nor in my code.

Note that in your code, you’re putting the JLabel into an extra JPanel, which uses FlowLayout by default, and add that panel to the frame. That’s why I said “keep in mind that you have to set up the layout manager such that they will shrink the JLabel when there’s not enough space”. The FlowLayout does not do that. In my example, the JLabel is added as center component to the frame and the BorderLayout will shrink it.

Sorry, I confused it with my another question (that does have that line)

What if I have a stack of JLabels that should have that behavior? I can't put them all in the center of a border layout-managed window

You have to decide for a particular layout manager and part of the decision making has to be the consideration whether the candidate has the desired shrinking behavior. GridLayout, for example, will shrink all components.

@demavi If you have a stack of JLabels and you find placing them in a JScrollPane clumsy, it’s probably because you’re trying to reinvent what a JList already does, without the clumsiness.

@Holger I discovered that IntelliJ's GridLayoutManager is not the same as the standard GridLayout. The former doesn't make its nested labels shrink. You may take a look
